# Windows 10: Connecto to pc with static IP address

Tags: windows, networking, router, mysql

Due to business, we need a special computer that will be a server. That computer will have a MySQL database installed, to which we will connect from other remote computers via a static IP address.

We bought a static IP address **89.216.**.**** from an internet provider.

We tried to configure it by following several internet instructions but it didn't work.

**We did the following:**

1. Control Panel > Wifi network adapters > properties
2. Double-click on "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)
3. We manually entered the enter IP address and subnet mask
   IP: 89.216.**.**.
   Subnet mask was automatically generated 255.0.0.0.0
   Gateway 89.216.**.1

After these settings, we completely lost the connection and somehow we got it back by going back to automatic ip assignment.

What exactly are we doing wrong? The provider told us it was a simple job of a few minutes. This has turned into hell!
How can we solve this and enable access to that computer from another location?

Comment: MySQL typically only allows connections from localhost, you have to specifically allow, remote access. How are you going to assign multiple computers a static IP address?

Comment: If the server is inside your local network, then use its LAN ip address, not a public address. If you really must use the public ip address, make sure your router supports NAT hairpinning. Otherwise, a client sends out a request to the router, it sees the ip as an internet one, sends it outside, the request is sent back, but was unexpected and thus is being ignored.

Comment: Also, strongly recommend AGAINST using wifi for a server connection. Wi-Fi works fine for personal device connections, but server connections require far more stability and reliability than Wi-Fi is designed to offer.

Comment: Thanks for answers. My sesrver pc with mysql is at my home. I need to connect to that pc from my work. Is that possible?